# SSL Certificate and Google Checkout

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, google-checkout

I have setup google checkout for my java web application and I want to recieve notifications of new orders and on recieving notificatification I want to execute some business logic.
I am using tomcat as application server. As I do not have a domain name so I am running my application on my personal machine which have a static IP. I am accessing my application from another machine like `https://my.static.IP:port/myWebApplication` and everything working fine. Now the problem is that google checkout notification needs SSL certificate. I did created a self signed SSL certificate for tomcat but google throwing following error for SSL certificate.

Error:

```
We encountered an error trying to access your server at https://my.static.IP:port/myWebApplication/notificationServlet -- the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'SSL_CERTIFICATE_ERROR' connecting to url 'https://my.static.IP:port/myWebApplication/notificationServlet'.
```

I have two queries here:-
1.) I am not sure how to create SSL certicficate for my ip so that it should be accepted fo google checkout notification.
2.) If it is not possible to create SSL for IP then is there some other way implementing google checkout notification whcich do not require SSL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an answer from Google: http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134466

So, seems you should buy a certificate in order to use it.

Comment: As Mihai states, no, it's only necessary depending on how you choose to implement....

Answer (score 1):

If you're using version 2.5 of the Checkout Notification API you do not need SSL:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Notification_API.html